# RealmResult iteration through thousands of objects is slow

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, realm

I have a project where I make a request to get some objects. This is the fastest implementation I have after making some tests but I feel I'm missing something. I have 2000 objects in database for my tests and the code before the computation takes 3.25 seconds to execute.

```
    val allSessions = realm.where(Session::class.java).isNotNull("endDate").findAll()

    // added for better performances
    val sessionsList = realm.copyFromRealm(allSessions)

    val sessionGroup1 = mutableListOf<Session>()
    val sessionGroup2 = mutableListOf<Session>()

    // otherwise the bottleneck is here, the foreach is slow
    sessionsList.forEach { session ->
        if (session.isGroup1()) {
            sessionGroup1.add(session)
        } else {
            sessionGroup2.add(session)
        }
    }

    // doComputations(), like sums, averages...
```

I have to access values for all objects to performs sum, averages and so on.
What would be the fastest way to do that?

Comment: Why are you copying them from the Realm? :o

Comment: It's my current fatest implementation at the moment. Otherwise, I've some foreach on the RealmResult object that are very slow

Comment: Then that means you are using many items and there isn't much more to be done, I guess

Comment: I'm not well versed in performance but it feels slow to me

Comment: @EpicPandaForce shouldn't we avoid dealing with managed object? my wild guess is managed object works similar way as in memory db. i may be wrong

Comment: @Aks4125 this depends entirely on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you only want to do sum and averages - use the builtin functions in Realm for that. If you need to do more advanced calculations getting the values out of Realm may be the fastest. But inform exactly what you need to do?

You should show how much time is spend copying out values and how much time is spend iterating over them. Measure what is really taking the time (use xcode profiler perhaps).
Alternatively, it's not clear how big your objects are and what else they contain, so it may be faster copying out just the properties you need to analyze versus the whole object.

Comment: Thanks @bmunk. I do more than sums and averages and have a lot of stats so I doubt the builtin Realm functions will help me. How do you copy the properties? Just as a precision I'm on Android Studio with Kotlin

Comment: copyFromRealm will copy all properties of your Realm objects to new local objects. I don't know if it's relevant or faster to just copy the properties you are doing stats on rather than copying the entire object. But you would just iterate allSessions and copy the relevant allSessions properties to local variables and then do your calculations.
But first - figure out exactly which part is slow. Android Studio also has performance profiler: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler

Answer (score 2):

try making `endDate` field as Index field using annotation.

from [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/):

> Like primary keys, this makes writes slightly slower , but makes reads faster. (It also makes your Realm file slightly larger, to store the index.) It’s best to only add indexes when you’re optimizing the read performance for specific situations.

```
import io.realm.annotations.Index;
@Index
private String endDate;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did but the performance gain was something like 10%, which is not bad but I feel there is more to do!

Comment: where exactly performance is dropping? can you post code what are you doing with `sessionsList`?

Comment: You can minimize loop by fetching query based results from Realm. fetch session based result list. if you are going with this approach then try making group field as index too.

Comment: I'm unsure what that means in terms of code or how that differs from the code I started writing? The origin of my objects is a Realm.where...findAll()

Comment: similar to `RealmResults<Session> sessionGroup1 = realm.where(...).equalTo("group1", true).findAll()`

Comment: It's actually slower :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to have achieved much better results using the following:

- `@Index` does help, not by a lot in my case but still
- I made a dedicated computable object as small as possible
- I used `RealmResults.sum()` which is so fast you should absolutely consider it
- I reversed the direction of a relationship to speed up queries

Currently at 0.38s while keeping a for loop in my code, otherwise basic calculations takes 0.16s, so I'm in between a 10x to 20x performance gain!

Note: I no longer use `realm.copyFromRealm(allSessions)`